# Scraping Javascript Text with Python and Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to pull latitude and longitude from TripAdvisor restaurants. The information isn't prominently displayed on the web page but I did find it in the HTML here:

[Latitude and Longitude w/in Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoZb9.png)

I am trying to use this code to pull all the information:

```
#import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

for i in range(0, 30, 30):
    #need this here for when you want more than 30
    while i <= range:
        i = str(i)
        #url format offsets the restaurants in increments of 30 after the oa
        url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294217-oa' + i + '-Hong_Kong.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
        r1 = requests.get(url1)
        data1 = r1.text
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
        for link in soup1.findAll('a', {'property_title'}):
            #print 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
            restaurant_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
            browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python27\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
            # use xpath to get to the information in the JS
            print browser.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/script[22]""")
```

When I run the code it tells me it is unable to find the element. Maybe I am a little brain dead right now, but if a fresh set of eyes could take a look at this and let me know if I am doing this wrong or if there is a different way to go about this I am all ears.

Comment: Not sure of your problem, but `while i <= range:` is not valid, as `range` is a function.

Comment: Thank you i'll look into that. If you look at the link of the image I posted. I am trying to pull that information in that photo. But when I run it, it tells me that the code is unable to locate the element in the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` packages when you are using `selenium webdriver` as selenium can open a webpage`(requests)` and fetch the content`(BeautifulSoup)` on its own. Below is the rough structure of what you are trying to accomplish plainly using selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python27\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
for counter in range(0, 30, 30):
    #need this here for when you want more than 30
    while i <= counter:
        i = str(i)
        url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294217-oa' + i + '-Hong_Kong.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
        browser.get(url1) # this will redirect to webpage
        # use xpath to get to the information in the JS
        print browser.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/script[22]""")
```